# Program crashes when reading a long text file - "*.exe has stopped working"

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, file-io

RRThe title describes it all. I am reading various files in my program, and once it reaches a relatively large file, the program crashes.

I wrote a shortened version of my program that replicates the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

char** load_File(char** preComputed, const int lines, const int sLength,
                 std::string fileName){
    //Declarations
    FILE *file;
    int C = lines+1;
    int R = sLength+2;
    int i; //Dummy index
    int len;

    //Create 2-D array on the heap
    preComputed = (char**) malloc(C*sizeof(char*));

    for(i = 0; i<C; i++) preComputed[i] = (char *) malloc(R*sizeof(char));
    //Need to free each element individually later on

    //Create temprary char array
    char* line = (char *) malloc(R*sizeof(char));
    assert(preComputed);

    //Open file to read and store values
    file = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "r");
    if(file == NULL){ perror("\nError opening file"); return NULL;}
    else{
        i = 0;
        while(fgets(line, R, file) != NULL){
            //Remove next line
            len = R;
            if((line[len-1]) == '\n') (line[len-1]) = '\0';
            len--; // Decrement length by one because of replacing EOL
                   // with null terminator     

            //Copy character set
            strcpy(preComputed[i], line);
            i++;
        }
        preComputed[C-1] = NULL; //Append null terminator
        free(line);
    }
    return preComputed;
}

int main(void){
    char** preComputed = NULL;
    std::string name = "alphaLow3.txt";

    system("pause");

    preComputed = load_File(preComputed, 17576, 3, name);
    if(preComputed == NULL){
        std::cout<<"\nAn error has been encountered...";
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    //Free preComputed
    for(int y = 0; y < 17576; y++){
        free(preComputed[y]);
    }
    free(preComputed);
}
```

This program will crash when it is executed. Here are two links to the text files.

1. [alphaLow3.txt](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=6157DCB01532062!952&authkey=!AHHjlm5lNC4UKN8&ithint=file%2c.txt)
2. [alphaLow2.txt](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=6157DCB01532062!955&authkey=!AMkG7O5ZbiyIpEc&ithint=folder%2c)

To run alphaLow2.txt, change the numbers in the `load_file` call to `676` and `2` respectively.

When this program reads alphaLow2.txt, it executes successfully. However, when it read alphaLow3.txt, it crashes. This file is only 172KB. I have files that are a MB or larger. I thought I allocated enough memory, but I may be missing something.

The program is supposed to be in `C`, but I've included some `C++` functions for ease.

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Comment: run the program in a debugger - that will tell you exactly what is going wrong

Comment: Fair enough, I know that it is hitting a segmentation fault

Comment: What does fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) do? sizeof(line), specifically.

Comment: This statement reads the file indicated by `file` (3rd argument), reads the number of characters specified by sizeof(line), and copies it into line. This may be source of my errors now that I think about it. sizeof(line) may be just returning the size of the datatype...Never Mind, it is not the issue.

Comment: `sizeof(line)` :  `line` is pointer. you use R instead.

Comment: Yes, I just modified that...`= 4 bytes`. At least in this program. However, it is not the cause of my issues.

Comment: Well, with the modifications I made to the program, both files cause the program to crash...

Comment: need `#include <cstring>` for `strcpy`

Comment: You have `preComputed[C-1] = NULL`, which in your example means `preComputed[17575]` will be NULL. In your loop where you do `free(preComputed[y])`, it is probably not going to go well when you try to free `preComputed[17575]`.

Comment: The program still isn't working though. I believe I've identified two errors. One is when reading alphaLow3.txt. For some reason, it reads the last character, `zzz`, then goes back to the beginning and reads `aaa`, then it seg faults. No idea why it does that. The second is when reading alphaLow2.txt. It crashes at the return.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `17577`

Comment: "alphaLow3.txt" : line of 35152 >> 17577

Comment: alphaLow3.txt has 35152 lines.

Comment: Well, I have no idea why it has that many lines. It should have 26^3 = 17576 lines. Now I just have to figure out why the program is crashing for all files now.

Comment: repeat from line of 17577.

Comment: 1. Why is preComputed an argument not a local variable? Return value is pointer to array of line buffers which will be owned and disposed by the caller.
2. Suggest use strncpy(preComputed[i], line, R); to prevent overrun if input file exceeds line length spec sLength.
3. What happens if lines is not sufficient? You're vulnerable to damage from malformed or corrupt input files, since you don't validate input file line count or line length.
4. Are you sure your input files are ASCII encoded?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY you're right, the preComputed[C-1] = NULL won't be an issue. I regret the error.

Comment: `len = R;` ----> `len = strlen(line);`

Comment: I believe it works either way.

Comment: `free(preComputed[y])` again, Part of the unreleased exists.

Comment: What do you mean again?

Comment: R = 3 + 2 = 5 , input data `aaa\n\0`, len = R -> line[len-1] -> line[4] --> '\0'

Comment: again : because Mark Plotnick pointed out, malloc, free not match.

Answer (score 1):

You must confirm your file length.In the alphaLow3.txt file, a total of 35152 lines.But in your program,you set the line 17576.This is the main reason leading to crash.

In addition,this sentence

```
if((line[len-1]) == '\n') (line[len-1]) = '\0';
```

fgets will make the last character NULL.For example the first line should be " 'a''a''a''\n''null' ".So you should do it like this.

```
if((line[len-2]) == '\n') (line[len-2]) = '\0';
```